# Spring boot application shutting down unexpectedly and log issues

Tags: spring-boot, logging, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

I have a web app developed with spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE. The application is currently on production serving user base of ~3000 users while running on two servers.

My issue is when I shutdown applications for a new release and start new version sometimes after running for one hour or so application go down automatically. I can see the log for shutdown hook in logs but no other errors.

`2018-07-12 05:46:40.100 DEBUG  --- [Thread-7] l.d.o.w.OMApplication : !!!!!!!!!!! application shutdown !!!!!!!!!!!`

When I start the instance again then it'll run until I shutdown willingly for any time without any issues under high load. I shutdown the application by sending a kill signal to the application and waiting till process exists ( gracefully shutting down).

I'm trying to pin point where the issue is and before the actual issue I think I have a problem with my logs. I have custom log configuration for business requirements. My error logs are not working properly and in error log even though I have configured to log error level I can see all other logs are printing there. My configuration is as follows.

```

```
<property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs/om"/>
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

<appender name="auditLogAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/audit.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/all.log}"/>-->
<!--<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>-->

<appender name="trace" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/request-trace.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/request-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="REPOSITORY_PERF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/repository-perf.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/repository-perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="CONTROLLER_PERF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/controller-perf.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/controller-perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="INTEGRATION_PERF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/integration-perf.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/integration-perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="SERVICE_PERF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/service-perf.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/service-perf-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ERROR_LOG_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/error.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--spring log appender-->

<appender name="SPRING_LOG_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/spring.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/spring-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ORDER_LOG_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/order.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/order-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="TRACKED_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/tracked.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/tracked-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p %mdc --- [%t] %C{1} : %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="lk.ravinda.om" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="SPRING_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="SPRING_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache" level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="SPRING_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="lk.ravinda.crm.repositoryutil.aspects" level="off">
    <appender-ref ref="SPRING_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="lk.ravinda.om.crm.impl" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ORDER_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>
<!--end spring log appender config-->


<logger name="SERVICE" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_PERF"/>
</logger>
<logger name="CONTROLLER" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="CONTROLLER_PERF"/>
</logger>
<logger name="INTEGRATION" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="INTEGRATION_PERF"/>
</logger>
<logger name="REPOSITORY" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="REPOSITORY_PERF"/>
</logger>

<logger name="auditLog" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="auditLogAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="TRACKED_LOGGER" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="TRACKED_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com" level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="lk.ravinda" level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_APPENDER"/>
</logger>

<logger name="trace" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="trace"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

```

I suspect somehow spring related errors are not printing in error.log and spring.log.

Appreciate any comments idea on this to find issue with application shutting down.

Comment: Are you using a fat jar directly or did you deploy your application on a webserver like tomcat ?  You set the ROOT logger at info level on console. Do you get something in this log ?

Comment: If your OS is Linux it's worth taking a look at system logs (`journactl` or `/var/log/messages`).

Comment: @wargre I'm using a fat jar built by spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

As for the logging not appearing - it looks like you have to elements specifying appenders for the same category "org.springframework", and I don't think Log4J will combine the two.  You probably should have a single element for that category with both appenders in it, then configure the "threshold" attribute in each appender so that one only has error level messages, while the other includes everything up to debug level...

I saw this here:
http://ibswings.blogspot.com/2009/03/log4j-configuration-controlling-logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of custom logs try once with pre configured log4j configuration in spring boot.
In application.properties file use :
logging.level.{application package name}=ERROR

{application package name } such as com.xyz.myapplication. package in which main class is present.
Hope it helps